# Discard 4-digit Number Beginning with Hypen

Tags: javascript, regex

In attempting some number validation, there is one case I want to exclude a number - if it contains a hyphen before the four digits.

To simplify my regular expression, let's only worry about those 4 digits.

Since I'm using JavaScript, I can't use lookbehinds.

In an attempt to use a negative lookahead to match anything not containing a hyphen, I came up with:

```
((?!-).)\d{4}
```

My test data is below, bolded are the matches:

```
2014
1106 **2014** **9899**
**11500**

234-233-2014
234-234-1100
-1100
```

Where my expectation is that 2014, 1106, 2014 and 9989 match, whereas 11500 does not. I know the issue is with the period is due to the fact that it matches anything except for line breaks. I also am trying to consider line breaks as I apply the word boundaries to my regular expression.

Might there be a better solution where I can match only a 4 digit number not followed by a hyphen, or simply exclude any matches if they are preceded by a hyphen?

Comment: By the way, if you want a "multi-line" period wildcard, substitute the period in question with `[\s\S]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through regex only,

```
(?:(?!\b-\b|-\b)(?:.|^))\b(\d{4})\b
```

Get the numbers from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kB8pY9/3)

And your js code would be,

```
> console.log(text.match(/(?:(?!\b-\b|-\b)(?:.|^))\b(\d{4})\b/g));
[ '2014', ' 1106', ' 2014', ' 9899' ]
```

**OR**

```
> function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
... index || (index = 1);
... var matches = [];
... var match;
...     while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
.....         matches.push(match[index]);
.....     }
... console.log(matches);
... }
undefined
> var matches = getMatches(text, re, 1);
[ '2014', '1106', '2014', '9899' ]
```

<sub>Code stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/3297613) :-)</sub>

Comment: In your case, you need only one line `console.log(text.match(/(?:(?!\b-\b|-\b)(?:.|^))\b(\d{4})\b/g));` ;) [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/zafixusejafo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @hex494D49 so match function gives the first preference to groups. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, `match()` returns an array containing the matches. In case you have more groups, match[0] will contain the whole match. But in this case match[0] = 2014, match[1] = 1106 ...

Comment: Nicely done, and showing the matches in JS is a nice step, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although this doubles up your searches, you can do a lookahead with both a positive and negative component to it:

```
(?=(?!-)\d{4})\b\d{4,}\b
```

This [regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/kB8pY9/1) doesn't capture the numbers, where this [regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/kB8pY9/2) does.

Comment: Since the OP is looking to match digits, wouldn't `\D` be better than `\b`?

Comment: @RobG: `\b` is a zero-length word boundary match, where `\D` will actually match a single non-digit character (it is equivalent to `[^0-9]`, which will also include the `-` that the OP wishes to exclude).

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround in JavaScript using `replace()`

```
var text = "2014 \
1106 2014 9899 \
 11500 \
\
234-233-2014 \
234-234-1100 \
-1100";

var a = [];
text.replace(/(-?\b\d{4}\b)/g, function(m){
  if(!m.match(/-/g)) a.push(m);  
});

console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
["2014", "1106", "2014", "9899"]
```

[Working jsBin](http://jsbin.com/regoracejava/1/edit?html,js,output)

---

Previous attempt (using look-behind which isn't supported in JavaScript)

```
/(?<!-)\b(\d{4})\b/g
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wM1qO0/1)

Comment: Javascript doesn't support look-behinds. This won't work in Javascript.

Comment: ^ Exactly, plus I had mentioned I can't use them in my post. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Sorry! I'll try to fix it; otherwise I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Match either four digits that are the beginning of a line, or four digits that don't come after a hyphen:

```
/[^-]\b\d{4}\b|^\b\d{4}\b/
```

Comment: I would match at the beginning of the line if every instance were like that. However the issue with `[^-]` is that matches any character except the hyphen, meaning it matches line breaks and white spaces, etc., before it matches 4 digits.